# UiScrollable not work in Android uiautomator

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

Does anyone try the android `UITesting` framework `UIAutomator`?
When I use the class `UiScrollabl`" to find some objects in a *scrollable* object, it can't find the object if the the length of the *scrollable* object is too long(need to swipe twice to find it), like "Developer options" in the "Settings" app.
Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 8):

I've fixed it by overriding a `UiScrollable` class.

```
public class UiScrollable extends com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable {

    public UiScrollable(UiSelector container) {
        super(container);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrollIntoView(UiSelector selector) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        if (exists(getSelector().childSelector(selector))) {
            return (true);
        } else {
            System.out.println("It doesn't exist on this page");
            // we will need to reset the search from the beginning to start search
            scrollToBeginning(getMaxSearchSwipes());
            if (exists(getSelector().childSelector(selector))) {
                return (true);
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < getMaxSearchSwipes(); x++) {
                System.out.println("I'm going forward a page: " + x);
                if(!scrollForward() && x!=0) { // x!=0 is the hack
                    return false;
                }

                if(exists(getSelector().childSelector(selector))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }    

}
```

I've copied the source from: [UiScrollable.java](http://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/jb-mr0-release%5E1/uiautomator/library/src/com/android/uiautomator/core/UiScrollable.java) (which may be outdated at some point, beware) and simply changed the `if(!scrollForward() && x!=0)` line.

From my observations, in the case of the example code on Google's ui testing page that scrolls the apps screen for the settings app, the `scrollForwards()` method fails on the first attempt. God knows why.

The above simply says if it fails on the first scroll, carry on regardless. If it fails to scroll on the second scroll, then it does in fact return a failure.

Answer (score 5):

To find and any element in a view where scrolling is required I used the below mentioned method and it seems to work fine.

```
public void searchForText(String searchText)
            throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
        UiScrollable textScroll = null;
        UiObject text = null;
        if (searchText != null) {
            textScroll = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));
            textScroll.scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(searchText));
            text = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text(searchText));
            text.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Weird...this method didnt work for me either...it behaves the same way as getChildByText...it stops scrolling at around 67 elements

Answer (score 3):

Can you provide some more details please e.g.

- Which version of adt are you using?
- Which version of Android are the tests being run in/on?

The reason I ask these questions is because there are some version-specific problems with UIAutomator. For instance I discovered a scrolling problem running on devices with 4.2.2 of Android that seems similar to the one you mentioned. I coded a workaround where my code does the scrolling if the standard Android method doesn't seem to find the element I expect to be available.

I've reproduced the essence of my code here, you'll find the complete example at http://blog.bettersoftwaretesting.com/?p=84

```
      // The following loop is to workaround a bug in Android 4.2.2 which
      // fails to scroll more than once into view.
      for (int i = 0; i < maxSearchSwipes; i++) {

          try {
              appToLaunch = appViews.getChildByText(selector, nameOfAppToLaunch);
              if (appToLaunch != null) {
                  // Create a UiSelector to find the Settings app and simulate      
                  // a user click to launch the app.
                  appToLaunch.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
                  break;
              }
          } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
              System.out.println("Did not find match for " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
          }

          for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
              appViews.scrollForward();
              System.out.println("scrolling forward 1 page of apps.");
          }
      }
```

Note: I don't know if this code will solve your problem since I don't have an example of your app. If you are able to post your tests and the XML layout of the relevant UI it'd make it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: You may be interested in the fix below, overriding the uiscrollable class, since it will fix the issue in more than one place.

Answer (score 1):

I in general have more luck with `UiDevice`'s `drag()` than with `Scrollable`'s methods.

Comment: Great advice! I was having trouble with overlapping Scrollable elements, and drag was the only solution for it.

Answer (score 1):

I also meet `getChildByText` only scroll once , and I try to trace it.
I find the root cause may be from system.

When you call the `getChildByText` , its flow is :

```
getChildByText -> scrollIntoView -> scrollForward -> scrollSwipe
```

In `scrollSwipe` , system will run swipe command , wait , than find all `AccessibilityEvent` and filter `AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED` in current screen. This step make  UiScrollable scroll again or check it in the end.

But the bug is here , system can't return right `AccessibilityEvent`.

```
public boolean scrollSwipe(final int downX, final int downY, final int upX, final int upY,
        final int steps) {

    Runnable command = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipe(downX, downY, upX, upY, steps);
        }
    };

    // Collect all accessibility events generated during the swipe command and get the
    // last event
    ArrayList<AccessibilityEvent> events = new ArrayList<AccessibilityEvent>();

    runAndWaitForEvents(command,
            new EventCollectingPredicate(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED, events),
            Configurator.getInstance().getScrollAcknowledgmentTimeout());

    //**Root cause**
    //Some times the events list size will be 0 ,
    //but in fact it can scroll again. 
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,"events size = " + events.size());

    AccessibilityEvent event = getLastMatchingEvent(events,
            AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_SCROLLED);

    if (event == null) {
        // end of scroll since no new scroll events received
        recycleAccessibilityEvents(events);
        return false;
    }
    ...
    ..
    .
}
```

I think the best way is that Overriding the code and defining the suitable `MaxSearchSwipes` , and if the item is over this size , make the test fail.

```
public class UiScrollableFix extends UiScrollable {

public UiScrollableFix(UiSelector container) {
    super(container);
}

@Override
public boolean scrollIntoView(UiSelector selector) throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
    Tracer.trace(selector);
    // if we happen to be on top of the text we want then return here
    UiSelector childSelector = getSelector().childSelector(selector);
    if (exists(childSelector)) {
        return (true);
    } else {
        // we will need to reset the search from the beginning to start search
        scrollToBeginning(getMaxSearchSwipes());
        if (exists(childSelector)) {
            return (true);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < getMaxSearchSwipes(); x++) {
            Log.e("test", "x=" + x);
            boolean scrolled = scrollForward();
            if (exists(childSelector)) {
                return true;
            }
            //For avoiding the scroll fail.
            // if (!scrolled && x!=0) {
            //     return false;
            // }

        }
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollableObject.scrollIntoView(btn_1);
try {if(scrollableObject.scrollIntoView(btn_1))
    btn_1.click();
}
catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e){
System.out.print("error1: "+e);
}
```

not sure if this can help you but this is what I do in my app. The first line is to make it scroll until it finds btn_1, then if it finds the object, it will perform a click on it.